# Snowflake Data Reader displays wrong number of warehouses

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Context: 
I am using trial version of  Enterprise Edition of Snowflake;

1) Created a database and table with some data and warehouse COMPUTE_WH
2) created reader account and shared table to that reader account and warehouse to use as data consumer : TEST_WH

when i see as an Account admin logged in as in step1; i see two warehouses; count but displays only one warehouse and the same when i login as data consumer dispays 2 warehouses and dispays "TEST_WH"

in sceanrio : 
   1) I am provider of the data and data sharing to another reader account and created warehouse for the data consumer;
I want to track how much Provider account warehoused used and also how much data consumers are spending credits;

There are 2 issues here : 
    - Why the data consumer account displays two warehouses but as per that account it is only 1 warehouse being created and used; 
  - Data Provider account says two warehouses but does not display warehouse "test_wh" credits usage.
Has any observed this?

Comment: 1) How did you create a warehouse for data consumer? 2) Where do you see 2 warehouses?

Comment: 1) I created warehouse 1 in provider account and another in consumer account. 2) I see count 2 in provider account. And 1 in consumer account which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you can create a warehouse and share it with the consumer account. The Consumer account admin needs to create a warehouse and use it for data processing requests.

Can you kindly update this space with the steps that you performed in sharing the warehouse from the provider account?

In general, the virtual warehouses created by the consumer ma consume credits, which will be charged to your provider account. If you wish to control the amount of credits consumed monthly by the virtual warehouses in the reader account you can use the resource monitor to configure.

Ref : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-config.html#task-4-create-resource-monitors-optional

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
Provider account in account admin billing displays 2 warehouses.
I understand it is 1 warehouse of provider and other one is consumer account warehouse.
What I am saying is that in provider account count displayed is 2 and credits used 3.16 credits but provider account can see only that account warehouse, not what portion of consumer warehouse is in that 3.16 credits.
Just imagine there are 4 consumer accounts using different warehouses and provider does not have any visibility of who is consuming more credits.